# Dart timeout on await Future

Tags: asynchronous, dart

How to make a `await future` not last more than 5 seconds ?
I need it because in some networking operation, the connection is sometimes producing silent error. Hence my client just wait for hours with no response. Instead, I want it trigger an error when the clients waits for more than 5 seconds

My code can trigger the error but it is still waiting

```
Future shouldnotlastmorethan5sec() async {
  Future foo = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));;
  foo.timeout(Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: (){
    //cancel future ??
    throw ('Timeout');
  });
  await foo;
}
Future test() async {
  try{
    await shouldnotlastmorethan5sec(); //this shoud not last more than 5 seconds
  }catch (e){
    print ('the error is ${e.toString()}');
  }
}
test();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [Future.timeout](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Future/timeout.html) you need to use the return value to get the correct behaviour. In your case:

```
Future shouldnotlastmorethan5sec() {
  Future foo = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
  return foo.timeout(Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: (){
    //cancel future ??
    throw ('Timeout');
  });
}
```