# how to add timeout inside await function

Tags: flutter, dart, timeout, ntp

I have function like this

```
aa() async {
    try{
      tz.initializeTimeZones();
      var detroit = tz.getLocation('xxx');
      tz.setLocalLocation(detroit);
      DateTime v = await NTP.now();
      DateTime today = tz.TZDateTime.from(v, detroit);
      if(today==...){
        // do something
      }else{
        // do something
      }
    }catch(err){
      throw("err");
    }
  }
```

I would like to set timeout in `await NTP.now();` so after I wait for more than 5 seconds I would like to throw error timeout... is there a way to do that?
I was following this [Dart timeout on await Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593256/dart-timeout-on-await-future) but I get stuck to implement it to my code

Comment: `void main() async {
  print('start');
  var foo = await now().timeout(Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () => -1);
  print('end $foo');
}

Future<int> now() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {});
  return 999;
}`

Comment: @pskink thank you very much, your comment helps me so much :D

Comment: you can also remove `onTimeout: ...` and catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

Add timeout in NTP and then put in try catch

```
try {
      currentDate = await NTP.now(
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      );
    } on TimeoutException {
      currentDate = DateTime.now();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this might help you.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5),
 () { 
    //do something
   });
```

Comment: This only delays execution but it does not times out the function that lasts long